# adding an array of class objects into one master class object

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers, reference

for a project I had to create a class that had variables for feet and inches, and had a method to add these variables together from object 1 and object 2, then object 3, 4, and so on.

```
CDistance CDistance::add(const CDistance& yourDist) const
{
    CDistance total;
    total.feet += yourDist.feet;
    total.inches += yourDist.inches;
    /*if (total.inches > 12)
    {
        total.feet += (total.inches / 12);
        total.inches = total.inches % 12;
    }*/
    return total;
}
```

that's the method I have for adding, and here is a function in the main source file, where I process each class

```
void printAndAdd(const CDistance distList[], int size)
{
    CDistance new_total;
    new_total = distList[0].add(distList[1].add(distList[2].add(distList[3].add(distList[4]))));
    new_total.printDist();
}
```

And here is the method I use to print out the data on screen

```
void CDistance::printDist() const
{
    cout << "Feet: " << this->feet << "\n\n";
    cout << "Inches: " << this->inches << "\n\n";
}
```

I thought about using a for loop, for that 2nd line, but I'm having a bit of a problem. Whenever I print the data out, it's 0. As if the add function isn't working, which I'm not quite sure I even understand what I did. From what I think I'm doing, it's creating a new obejct, adding the variables from the referenced to object to the created object, that commented out section is a section I just took out for now and will add later, and then it returns the object. When I call the function in my main source file it would set the object  new_total equal to the sum of object 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4. Am I close, or way off to what's actually happening? I should also explain that I've only been programming for about a year, it's really intriguing to me, but naturally difficult at times, and I'm still trying to grasp my hands around the idea of classes in c++.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you never use the instance variables when adding. Instead you always start from a freshly minted object. Try this:

```
CDistance CDistance::add(const CDistance& yourDist) const
{
    CDistance total(*this);
    total.feet += yourDist.feet;
    total.inches += yourDist.inches;

    this->feet += yourDist.feet;
    this->inches += yourDist.inches;
    return total;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done some playing with your code and it looks like this line should is incorrect:

```
CDistance total;
```

The value of total is never initialized and is therefore always going to be whatever your default constructor has defined it to be (probably 0/0).  Thus, the result of that call will always end up whatever was passed to the input.  I think you meant to do this:

```
CDistance total = *this;
```

That will copy the current values for feet an inches into the temp and then the following lines will add the input.  Passing through the chain of calls like you do should now concatenate the additions as expected.